# I am trying to implement spring security ive configured everything but still not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

spring security not using details from database for authentication and generating password in console also not using my customized login form.

**Main class--**

```
package mis.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"mis.controller", "mis.services"})
@EntityScan("mis.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("mis.dao")
public class BitmisApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BitmisApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetails--**

```
package mis.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import mis.entity.Roles;
import mis.entity.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;


public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    
    private User user;
    
    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
 
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<Roles> roles = user.getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
         
        for (Roles role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
         
        return authorities;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }
    
}
```

**MyConfig class--**

```
package mis.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;



@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
         
        return authProvider;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "CREATOR", "EDITOR", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/new").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "CREATOR")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "EDITOR")
            .antMatchers("/delete/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            ;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl--**

```
package mis.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import mis.entity.User;
import mis.dao.UserRepository;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
         
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
          
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
            }
             
            return new CustomUserDetails(user);
        }

}
```

**UserRepository--**

" package mis.dao;

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import mis.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username")
    public User getUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}"
```

I think springboot is not able to read this authentication files

Comment: Have you tried setting `@ComponentScan({"mis"})`?

Comment: Due to your package structure things aren't picked up. Instead of placing your `BitmisApplication` in `mis.main` move it to `mis`. Ditch all the annotations but `@SpringBootApplication` and everything will work.

Comment: Yes ive tried but didnt work

Comment: please do not just post your code and explain in one sentence that it is not working. Where are your logs, the steps to reproduce, your requests, lack of debugging details, downvoted and voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the spring application can't find your configs since your project structure is faulty and you have added faulty custom configuration.

the `@SpringBootApplication` class will per default scan the package it is in `mis.main` and all packages below this one (mis.main.*.*.* etc) in order to find all spring annotated classes and load them.

You have placed your configuration files in `mis.config` which is not directly below `mis.main`, and you have files in `mis.entity` which is also not beneath `mis.main`.

You have also added

```
@ComponentScan({"mis.controller", "mis.services"})
@EntityScan("mis.entity")
```

in order to try to find the configuration files but failed to specify `mis.config` as a folder to scan in.

The simplest solution would be to

- remove to two annotations i mentioned above.
- move the main class into the package `mis` and then delete the package `mis.main` so that the main class is at the project root.

some other things:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
         
    return authProvider;
}
 
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

is not needed and can be removed, because you have declared a custom `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` as beans, they will automatically be picked up by the system and included into spring and it will set up DaoAuthentication for you automatically.

If you are learning you should read the spring security reference docs all this is mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me